# Updating Moment from version 2.1.0 to 2.13.0?

Tags: momentjs

Are there breaking changes in Moment from version 2.1.0 to 2.13.0?

I just inherited a code base that is using the older version and want to know if there will be problems upgrading to 2.13 from 2.1. Unfortunately there are no JavaScript unit tests for our web app.

Comment: The 2.0 change log is in a gist: https://gist.github.com/ichernev

Answer (score 2):

I can say that in general, moment follows [SemVer](http://semver.org/), so there are no breaking API changes.

However you may find some *behavioral* changes, as various bugs have been fixed over the years.  Some consider it a "breaking change" when they depended on a particular bug being exhibited and later the bug was fixed, or when a function was improved to be more semantically correct.

As an example, the string returned by `moment.utc().format()` used to include an offset of `+00:00`, and it now returns `Z`.  This more closely conforms to the ISO8601 and RFC3339 specifications, so the previous implementation was considered a bug, and it has since been resolved.  Most people were fine with this change, as either form should be accepted by all modern parsers, but a few folks complained that this broke their code because they were manually parsing the results via string manipulation, and expecting a numeric value for the offset.  We don't consider this a breaking change because the API didn't change, and the resulting string was compliant with the spec both before and after the change - it's just more accurate semantically now.

There are a few miscellaneous other changes like this, and they are all referenced in [the changelog](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md). If you edit your question to show which features of moment you are using, then I might be able to provide more details.